# Changing width of table lines

Tags: tables, rules, width

We know that by adding `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{xpt}` changes the thickness of all the table lines.

If I wanted to change specific table lines, how to do it?

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.7pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1ex}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

First table remains with its thickness of the lines intact.
I want to change the thickness of all lines in second table. (Vertical and horizontal ones need to be equal.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Update

Use `\arrayrulewidth` from the preamble and place it before the desired table using a group to keep the change to `\arrayrulewidth` local:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1ex}

{
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can have individual rule control too:

For horizontal rules:

```
\noalign{\hrule height <length>}
```

instead of `\hline` (you can define a command for this). For vertical rules:

```
!{\vrule width <length>}
```

instead of `|` in the format specification. An example:

[image]

The code for the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\ChangeRT[1]{\noalign{\hrule height #1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{
  |c!{\vrule width 1pt}
  c!{\vrule width 1.6pt}
  c!{\vrule width 2.2pt}
  c!{\vrule width 2.8pt}
  c!{\vrule width 3.4pt}
  c!{\vrule width 4pt}
  c!{\vrule width 4.6pt}
  }
\hline
& & & & & & \\
\ChangeRT{1pt}
& & & & & & \\
\ChangeRT{1.6pt}
& & & & & & \\
\ChangeRT{2.2pt}
& & & & & & \\
\ChangeRT{2.8pt}
& & & & & & \\
\ChangeRT{3.4pt}
& & & & & & \\
\ChangeRT{4pt}
& & & & & & \\
\ChangeRT{4.6pt}
\end{tabular}\par\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c!{\vrule width 4pt}c|c!{\vrule width 8pt}}
\hline
column1a & column2a & column 3a \\
\ChangeRT{4pt}
column1b & column2b & column 3b \\
\hline
column1c & column2c & column 3c \\
\ChangeRT{2pt}
column1d & column2d & column 3d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package offers an optioanl argument to its rule commands control their thickness (vertical rules, of course, are not a good companion here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
\toprule[2pt]
a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\
\midrule[1pt]
a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\
\midrule
a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\
\cmidrule[2pt]{3-5}
a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\
\midrule
a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\
\bottomrule[5pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've expressed myself wrong. Can you take a look again? I've edited.

Comment: @Oshnaj Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

For horizontal rules, you can use the `boldline` package (from the `shipunov` bundle). It defines `\hlineB` and a `\clineB` commands, which use a `num` \arrayrulewidth argument.

An alternative is the `makecell` package, which defines its own `\Xhline` and `\Xcline` commands; they have a `dimension` argument.

For vertical rules, you can use `!{\vrule width x pt}` in the table preamble. `Boldline` defines a `V{num}` qualifier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{V{5}c|c|cV{5}}
    \hlineB{7.5}
    Fiddle & Dee & Dee \\
\clineB{1-2}{3}
Tweedledee &Tweedledum & \\
    \hlineB{5}
  \end{tabular}
  \vskip 3ex
  \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width2pt}c|c|c!{\vrule width2pt}}
\Xhline{3pt}
    Fiddle & Dee & Dee \\
\Xcline{1-2}{1.2pt}
Tweedledee &Tweedledum & \\
    \Xhline{2pt}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]