# How can I make vertical and horizontal lines in Longtable thicker?

Tags: longtable, line

For the following Longtable MWE, how can I make the third vertical line and the second horizontal line thicker than the other lines?

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
Row 2 & a & b & c \\ \hline
Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is the accepted answer to the similar problem of yours [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256731/changing-width-of-table-lines#256732). Is it helpful?

Comment: Not quite... the closest to success was with with V{num}, but it highlighted that for some reason the edges of the cells in my table aren't perfectly lined up vertically.  It may have worked in the MWE.

Comment: Well, solutions in the link seem to be working for me. You could try [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray). It provides very intuitive interface to create complex tables where lines, spaces, alignments, etc. are easy to tune. You don't really need any other package but code may take a bit longer to compile.

Comment: Okay - thanks for the suggestions.  Maybe there's something special about Longtable that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following example work for you

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{l | c | c !{\vrule width 2pt} c}
    \hline
    & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 \\
    \specialrule{.2em}{0em}{0em} \endhead
    \specialrule{.1em}{0em}{0em} \endfoot
    \specialrule{.2em}{0em}{0em} \endlastfoot
    Row 2 & a & b & c \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z \\ \hline
    Row 3 & x & y & z
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] |  |

Comment: Success!  Thanks very much.