# How to create this table?

Tags: tables

What is the simplest script to create something similar to this table?

[image]

**Edit: Thanks for the help so far. I apologize I have not included example. I am familiar with creating tables in `table` and `tabular` environments. Also one of the comments addressed the addition of the diagonal line. The only thing that I am not sure of is how to combine four subtables into one. Is there a previous answer in this site that address that?**

Comment: Do you have any starting code?

Comment: If you decide on using regular `tabular` environment, you need a few packages for that: [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) for custom horizontal rules, [makecell](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecell) to add diagonal rules. For custom vertical lines see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256732/31283). Additionally, use `multicolumn` to merge adjacent cells in a row. Otherwise have a look at [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), which is a relatively new package but has very intuitive interface. Beware you will need to manually add it to Overleaf.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell what you are looking for?

Comment: Instead of apologizing for not including example code, it would be better to include the example code.

Comment: You can either just use one large `tabluar` or you can try to arrange four `tabular` environments (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2832/47927 ). However, if you want to arrange multiple tables, note that there is a caption spanning over two subtables ("Error").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be a start for you:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering


\begin{tabular}{|ccccccc|}

\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Error}\\
\hline
&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{DIRK(5,5)}\\
\hline
\diaghead(-2,1){|ccccccc|}%
{g}{h}&
0.1&& 0.01& 0.001& 0.0001& 0.00001\\
\hline
1 && 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ & 0\\
10 && 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ & 0\\
100 && 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ & 0\\
1000 && 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ & 0\\
10000 && 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ & 0\\
\hline

\hline
&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{DIRK(9,7)}\\
\hline
\diaghead(-2,1){|ccccccc|}%
{g}{h}&
0.1&& 0.01& 0.001& 0.0001& 0.00001\\
\hline
1 && 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ & 0\\
10 && 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ & 0\\
100 && 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ & 0\\
1000 && 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ & 0\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it out!